# How do I create associations in gRPC proto files?

Tags: go, grpc-go

I'm might be going about it the wrong way, but I want to define a relationship between two or more structs (messages).

Using StackOverflow as an example, let's say I had a `LabelService` for CRUD actions on labels. I also have a `QuestionService` where a `Question` can have `Labels`. Let's also assume I have a `UserService` and a `User` can also have labels attached

```proto
# label.proto
service LabelService {
    rpc CreateLabel() returns();
    ...etc
}
message Label {
   string text = 1;
}
```

But now I want to create my `QuestionService` and `Question` message. Do I associate the two files some how or is this level of association done in the go code?

```proto
# question.proto
service QuestionService {
    rpc CreateQuestion() returns();
    ...etc
}
message Question {
   string text = 1;
   repeat Label labels = 2 # <-- how to do this?
}

# user.proto
service UserService {
    rpc CreateQuestion() returns();
    ...etc
}
message User {
   string name = 1;
   repeat Label labels = 2 # <-- how to do this?
}
```

I think I'm confused because for REST APIs and using gorm.io for example, I would setup the associations in the structs and have gorm.io create the tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#importing_definitions):

```
import "myproject/other_protos.proto";
```

so just simply add an `import` in your `question.proto` to your `user.proto`. It's no different than when importing other standard `proto` definitions like `timestamp` and `duration`:

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";
```

Comment: Awesome I didn't realise it was as simple as that, but its so obvious now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Did you already import user.proto in question.proto?

in question.proto

`import "user.proto"` <- i think you can use `Label labels`